# Diamondback SVN build; roscore won't start, ImportError: No module named rosgraph_msgs.msg

Tags: roscore, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just built **ROS Diamondback desktop full-install** from SVN using instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/SVN). Installation process run smoothly. When trying to run `roscore` the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ros/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in <module>
    from ros import roslaunch
  File "/home/user/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    return __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from roslaunch.scriptapi import ROSLaunch
  File "/home/user/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in <module>
    import roslaunch.parent
  File "/home/user/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 55, in <module>
    import roslaunch.server
  File "/home/user/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 70, in <module>
    from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
ImportError: No module named rosgraph_msgs.msg
```

`roswtf` gives the following output:

```
ERROR: ROS has not been built. To fix:
cd $ROS_ROOT
make
```

Of course doing as `roswtf` suggests or running `rosmake ros` doesn't fix the issue.

**EDIT:** The thing that seems suspicious to me is there are only 18 steps in the process of building ros via `rosmake ros`. This seems to little in comparison with 72 dependencies being built when building cturtle.

Any clues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9116/diamondback-svn-build;-roscore-won%27t-start,-importerror:-no-module-named-rosgraph_msgs.msg/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try running "rosmake ros_comm" and re-running?

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-28**:
rosinstall version 0.5.16 and greater now will bootstrap ros_comm if present.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-26**:
I've patched roswtf r13416.  Unfortunately, it won't make it in the final Diamondback RC, but we are also working to address the underlying cause better in rosinstall.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-25**:
Sounds like there is still a bug in roswtf to fix that message.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-02-20**:
Thank you, that solved the problem. I move on to reading REP108 :).

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-02-20**:
See also REP108 for details of how "ros" stack was broken up for diamondback: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html